# while copying the file to other file, giving error. cp: target is not a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When i am trying to run below code it is giving error of `cp: target "Featurespath" is not a directory`

I have tried multiple option but not working.

```
Featurespath=/permanent/jag/media-*/*/print/cooked/*Features.xml
for file in $(ls $Featurespath);
do
cat $Featurespath | sed "/pB-/s/Direction=\"unidir\"/Direction=\"bidir\"/" $Featurespath > /permanent/jag/temp.xml
cp -rf /permanent/jag/temp.xml $Featurespath
rm /permanent/jag/temp.xml
done
```

i want modified xml to be pasted in same xml file.

Comment: `man cp` and think about the options you're using. Your script has several additional issues, run it through http://shellcheck.net and read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs as a start.

Comment: `for file in /permanent/jag/media-*/*/print/cooked/*Features.xml`. Don't use `ls`, and putting the pattern in variable causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: `sed` reads from standard input *or* a named file argument, not both.

Comment: `sed` is not the right tool for working with XML.

Answer (score 2):

The error you received was because of the `cp` line: bash expands`$Featurespath` into a list of files. When `cp` sees more than 2 parameters, it assumes the last parameter to be a directory, which is not in this case. Here is my suggested fix:

```
Featurespath=/permanent/jag/media-*/*/print/cooked/*Features.xml
for file in $Featurespath
do
    sed "/pB-/s/Direction=\"unidir\"/Direction=\"bidir\"/" "$file" > /permanent/jag/temp.xml
    mv -f /permanent/jag/temp.xml "$file"
done
```

## Notes

- Do not use `ls`: bash can expand the wildcards just fine
- Within the loop, you are now dealing with individual files `$file`, not the list of file `$Featurespath`
- Do not need to use the `cat` command, the `sed` command can take a file name
- `sed` has an inline editing option, which eliminate the need for temp file. You might want to look into it.
- Replace `cp`/`rm` combination with `mv`
- Ultimately, like others have said, `sed` is not the right tool to edit XML contents, but it might work for simple cases